# toWriting a program for password, PIN, and PUK

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to create a program that will prompt the user to enter the correct password. The third time the password is not correctly entered, the program should ask the user for the PIN, if the user still fails to enter the PUK correctly for 3 attempts, the program now should print SIM BLOCKED.

I guess I have to use a loop but I don't know how. I am but just a newbie.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
    public class PinPUK {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Pin Code: ");
    int choice  = keyboard.nextInt();
    if (choice == 123) {
        System.out.println("Welcome!");    
        }
    else {
        System.out.println("Password is incorrect! Try again!"); // This is the 1st time the wrong password has been entered.
    }                                                           // 2 more and the program should ask for the PIN 3 times if incorrectly entered, and program should ask the PUK 3 times if it is incorrect, the program should now print SIM BLOCKED.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in main:

```
int attemps = 0;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Pin Code: ");
int PIN = 0;
int PUK = 0;
int CORRECT_PIN = 123;
int CORRECT_PUK = 1234;
while(PIN != CORRECT_PIN && attemps < 3)
        {
            PIN  = keyboard.nextInt();
            attemps++;
            if (PIN != CORRECT_PIN && attemps < 3) { 
               System.out.println("PIN is incorrect! Try again!" ); // This is the 1st time the wrong password has been entered.
            }
        }
        if (PIN == CORRECT_PIN && attemps <= 3) {  
            System.out.println("Welcome!");  
        }
         else {
           System.out.println("PIN is incorrect! Try again with PUK");
           attemps = 0;
           while(PUK != CORRECT_PUK && attemps < 3)
           {
            PUK  = keyboard.nextInt();
            attemps++;
            if (PUK != CORRECT_PUK && attemps < 3) { 
               System.out.println("PUK is incorrect! Try again!"); // This is the 1st time the wrong password has been entered.
            }
           }
        if (PUK == CORRECT_PUK && attemps <= 3) {  
            System.out.println("Welcome!");  
        }
        else
        {
           System.out.println("PUK is incorrect! SIM Blocked! See you!");
        }
        }
```

**Output 1:**

```
Enter Pin Code: 33 
PIN is incorrect! Try again!
3333
PIN is incorrect! Try again!
33333
PIN is incorrect! Try again with PUK
3333
PUK is incorrect! Try again!
333
PUK is incorrect! Try again!
333
PUK is incorrect! SIM Blocked! See you!
```

**Output 2:**

```
Enter Pin Code: 324234
PIN is incorrect! Try again!
123
Welcome!
```

**Output 3:**

```
Enter Pin Code: 4354
PIN is incorrect! Try again!
345
PIN is incorrect! Try again!
3455
PIN is incorrect! Try again with PUK
1234
Welcome!
```

If you would compare PIN with 0 use this:

```
String PIN = null;
String CORRECT_PIN = "0123";
do{
        PIN  = keyboard.next();
        attemps++;
        if (!PIN.equals(CORRECT_PIN) && attemps < 3) 
            { 
               System.out.println("PIN is incorrect! Try again!" );
            }
     }while(!PIN.equals(CORRECT_PIN) && attemps < 3);
```

Then in if statement use this:

```
PIN.equals(CORRECT_PIN)
```

instead of

```
PIN == CORRECT_PIN
```

Full code here:

```
int attemps = 0;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Pin Code: ");
String PUK = null;
String PIN = null;
String CORRECT_PIN = "0123";
String CORRECT_PUK = "01234";
do{
        PIN  = keyboard.next();
        attemps++;
        if (!PIN.equals(CORRECT_PIN) && attemps < 3) 
            { 
               System.out.println("PIN is incorrect! Try again!" );
            }
     }while(!PIN.equals(CORRECT_PIN) && attemps < 3);
            if (PIN.equals(CORRECT_PIN) && attemps <= 3) {  
                System.out.println("Welcome!");  
            }
             else {
               System.out.println("PIN is incorrect! Try again with PUK");
               attemps = 0;
            do{
                PUK  = keyboard.next();
                attemps++;
                if (!PUK.equals(CORRECT_PUK) && attemps < 3) 
                    { 
                       System.out.println("PIN is incorrect! Try again!" );
                    }
             }while(!PUK.equals(CORRECT_PUK) && attemps < 3);
            if (PUK.equals(CORRECT_PUK) && attemps <= 3) {  
                System.out.println("Welcome!");  
            }
            else
            {
               System.out.println("PUK is incorrect! SIM Blocked! See you!");
            }
            }
```

Comment: thank you! It works but the attempts should include the first time the user types a pin, anyway, I have figured it with changing the 3 to 2 the same with the PUK number of attempts. and, can you please delete the "attempts" I am still figuring it out how to remove in the source code that you supplied

Comment: if you want to control the pin 0 of forwards you should compare the strings not integers @TristanCoal-Crescent

Comment: I am confused, the string and int, I cannot separate them huhu

Comment: I edit it @TristanCoal-Crescent if you are confused I add full code

Comment: Sorry, but I still cannot make it work... we have just discussed this in school and no actual practice in a computer so I really need to study well...can you please edit it for me...I cannot make it work.. @Michele Lacorte

Comment: WOW! You are such a nice person! Thank you! Words are not enough to express how thankful I am but at least I can partially express it thru that word... Thank you from the bottom of my heart... this really helps ♥♥♥

Comment: You're welcome! , however, this program is simple, could be making millions of improvements to the code , I suggest you read some tutorials of java , or if something is not clear there is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using the following snippet:

```
int count = 0;
while(count<3) {
    if (choice == 123) {
        System.out.println("Welcome!"); 
        break;   //break from the loop
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Password is incorrect! Try again!");
    }
    count++;
}

if(count == 3) {
     System.out.println("SIM BLOCKED");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PinPUK {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Pin Code: ");
    int tries = 0;
    boolean correctPin = false;
    while(!correctPin) {
        //It is better to scan the next line and parse the integer
        int choice  = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
        if (choice == 123) {
           System.out.println("Welcome!"); 
           correctPin = true;   
        }
        else if (tries < 3{
            System.out.println("Password is incorrect! Try again!"); 
       }    
       else if (tries >= 3)
          System.out.println("SIM blocked");
       }
   }
}
```